# Tuning ORACLE Network properties

Tags: java, oracle, networking, jdbc, oracle12c

We have recently updated from `Oracle 11g` to `Oracle 12c` RDBMS. Upon upgrading we noticed a decline in responsiveness of our application, which is running within `Wildfly9`.

To pinpoint the source of our problem we started executing and measuring statements from a plain java test-application. Doing so, we found, that querying the oracle-server via network is significantly slower than querying directly on the same machine, where the DBMS is installed.

Next step was an in-depth analysis of the network traffic generated between the machines. We found, the absolute majority of packets is less than 65 bytes in size and at the same time, the oracle server seems to expect acknowledgments for every packet sent to client. These two issues together obviously form the base of a severe problem.

While we cannot roll back to oracle 11g and do a direct comparison, we assume this behavior was not present there.

Has anyone seen this behavior before or has any idea regarding this issue?

Comment: Have you also upgraded the driver? If you're using an old version of the driver (say pre 11.2) I suggest you upgrade the driver too. The SDU size has been increased in 12c so it may be worth using the driver from 12c.

Comment: @JeandeLavarene: We upgraded the driver as well, wen we updated the database. Subjectively matters got worse, when we went from the 12.0.1 to the 12.0.2 driver, which solves a major bug.

Comment: Which packets are you talking about? TCP packets? or NS protocol packets? If it's TCP packets then there isn't much you can do at the Oracle level. TCP may decide to send smaller packets because of your network topology. If it's NS packets then can you explain what your workload looks like? The default SDU size is 8kB so  you should see much larger packets.

Comment: @JeandeLavarene: it is TCP packets. Funny thing is, that there are larger than 65 byte packets in the dump we got, so technically the network layer is capable of sending larger packets. This is in line with the fact, that the configured MTU for the system/network is 1500 byte.

Comment: Are you setting the value of send_buf_size and recv_buf_size in sqlnet.ora on your server? Also is your client machine remote?

Comment: @JeandeLavarene: We are not setting buffer-sizes and the client-machine we tested with was remote

Comment: If the client-machine you tested with was remote then, depending on how remote, this could explain why you're seeing very small TCP packets. I suggest you try again with a client machine on the same LAN.

Comment: @JeandeLavarene: We just did set up a VM within the same network and are seeing virutal identical threaddumps.